# Not entering the success part of http response in angularjs using spring mvc

Tags: java, html, angularjs, spring-mvc

Please anyone help me to resolve this problem.

**java**

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/employeelogincheck/{emailid}/{password}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String EmployeeLoginCheck(
  @PathVariable("emailid") String emailid,
  @PathVariable("password") String password) {
  System.out.println("EmployeeLoginCheck");
  System.out.println(password);
  System.out.println(emailid);
  return emailid;
}
```

**javascript**

```js
var app = angular.module('signIn', [])
{
  app
  .controller(
    'signInController',
    function($scope, $http, $window) {
      $scope.emailid = '';
      $scope.password = '';
      $scope.getvalues = function() {
        var email = $scope.emailid;
        var pass = $scope.password;
        return $http
        .get(
          'employeelogincheck/'
          + email + '/'
          + pass)
        .then(
          function(response) {
            alert("hai");
            return response.data;
            //var data = response.data;
            //alert(data);
            $window.location.href = '/EmployeeManagement/employeeloginsuccess.html';
          });
      }
    });
}
```

**html**

```html
<form ng-app="signIn" ng-controller="signInController"
      name="signinform" novalidate>
  <p>
    <input type="email" value="" name="emailid" ng-model="emailid"
           placeholder="Email-Id" required />
  </p>
  <p>{{result}}</p>
  <p>
    <input type="password" value="" name="password"
           ng-model="password" placeholder="Password" required />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="SignIn" ng-click="getvalues()">
  </p>
</form>
```

Please help some one... and i don't getting at least a string value from java controller.

Comment: is the controler part of java is correct?

Comment: what is the error ? what problem you are facing.

Comment: no any errors .i am trying to get a return value ie emailid from the java controller part to the angularjs http success part

Comment: but the value is not get in the js

Comment: According to your code value, you will get from java in `response` object, first add console and check what you are getting in response.